# converting RGB numpy matrix to greyscale martix

Tags: python, rgb, grayscale

I want to convert rgb matrix to greyscale martix without directly opening the image file as the process is very slow in python?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know if opening an image in python is slow? Or how to convert rgb to greyscale using numpy? Please provide your code so we can help improve / fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a tour in the [Help Center] to see what kind of questions are likely to be answered and what are likely to be closed.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, it would be good if you can add more details and what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you always have to load image into python program if you want to process it. If you dont wan to use image procesing library, you can do all with numpy (for example OpenCV works with numpy arrays anyway, so I would be using OpenCV)

If you want to use purely matrixes(numpy) you can use for saving and loading

```
matrix = np.load('image.npy')
np.save('grayscale.npy',grayscale)
```

**For processing:**

Suppose you have have numpy matrix with this RGB shape:

```
>>> matrix.shape
(1000, 1000, 3)
```

In order to transform it into grayscale without doing any 'image processing', you can simply do MEAN over 3rd. dimension (color dimension)

```
grayscale = matrix.mean(axis=-1) # you can use axis=2 or as Nils Werner pointed out: axis=-1 which is more general

>>> grayscale.shape
(1000,1000)
```

Result:

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER MEAN
[image]

Comment: I usually prefer to use `axis=-1` because it it's a little bit more general and i.e. let's you convert hundreds of images at once if you pass it an array of shape `(100, 100, 100, 3)`.